# Posting JavaScript objects with Ajax and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: arrays, ajax, model-view-controller

How can I post a list from view to controller using ajax? I have this code in client side:

```
    $(".js-save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var lstERegistroVenta = [];
        var ERegistroVenta = new Object();
        ERegistroVenta.IdProducto = 1;
        ERegistroVenta.IdInventario = 2;
        ERegistroVenta.MontoProducto = 12.5;
        ERegistroVenta.CantidadProducto = 1;
        ERegistroVenta.MontoTotalSinIGV = 20.5
        ERegistroVenta.MontoTotal = 23.5
        lstERegistroVenta.push(ERegistroVenta);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/API/Inventario/Venta/1",
            data: JSON.stringify({ lstERegistroVenta: lstERegistroVenta }),
            success: function () {
                toastr.success("Correcto");
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr.error("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

When I try to pass the data I receive only empty list. In server side I have this API

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("API/Inventario/{Venta}/{IdProducto}")]
    public IHttpActionResult AsignarProducto(int IdProducto,List<ERegistroVenta> lstERegistroVenta)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

public class ERegistroVenta
{
    public int IdProducto { get; set; }
    public int IdInventario { get; set; }
    public double MontoProducto { get; set; }
    public int CantidadProducto { get; set; }
    public double MontoTotalSinIGV { get; set; }
    public double MontoTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't suggest calling an API method directly from a View. Instead, call a controller method which should internally call the API method. The code for this would look something like below.

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/TestController/TestMethod",
        data: { "IdProducto" : "1", "lstERegistroVenta": lstERegistroVenta },
        success: function () {
            toastr.success("Correcto");
        },
        error: function () {
            toastr.error("Error");
        }
});

   [HttpPost]
   public void TestMethod(int IdProducto,List<ERegistroVenta> lstERegistroVenta)
   {
        // Your Logic Here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Maybe my mistake was that I didn't send an anonymous list of objects.
Take a look to this:https://kwilson.io/blog/post-an-array-of-objects-to-webapi-using-jquery/
My solution below:

```
    $(".js-save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var lstERegistroVenta = [];
        var ERegistroVenta = new Object();
        ERegistroVenta.IdProducto = 1;
        ERegistroVenta.IdInventario = 2;
        ERegistroVenta.MontoProducto = 12.5;
        ERegistroVenta.CantidadProducto = 1;
        ERegistroVenta.MontoTotalSinIGV = 20.5
        ERegistroVenta.MontoTotal = 23.5
        lstERegistroVenta.push(ERegistroVenta);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/API/Inventario/Venta/1",
            data: { '': lstERegistroVenta },
            success: function () {
                toastr.success("Correcto");
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr.error("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

And in server side:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("API/Inventario/{Venta}/{IdProducto}")]
public IHttpActionResult AsignarProducto(int IdProducto,List<ERegistroVenta> lstERegistroVenta)
{
    // Logic Here
}
```

Hope this helps to another user.